# Aurelia: router without losing state

Tags: aurelia, router

Here is my problem:

I typically have a paginated datagrid with a lot of rows. I want to be able to edit the data for each row of course but I have 2 constraints on this:

- I need the edition form to replace the content of the page (I don't want a popup, modal dialog or side panel)
- I don't want to lose the state of the datagrid: maybe I navigated down 5 pages in the datagrid and I don't want to be reloaded on the first page. And actually, I'd rather not reload the data I already had (the edited data will be updated automatically by my persistence layer anyway).

Ideally, I would have liked to have some kind of subrouter but I'm not sure how it would fit the first requirement. Otherwise, I could have a component that would be hidden by default and positions itself on top of the datagrid view when necessary but that feels quite hacky and forces me to have everything in the same template. And I will have to handle a stack of these components if I have several different 'full-screen panel'...

Any idea on a correct way to implement this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried different solutions to no avail unfortunately. I had a long discussion with @Kukks on gitter and we agreed that using subrouters and viewports might be a bit overkill for my use case.

I reverted to my original idea of using absolutely positioned components to hide the previous one in a kind of "deck layout". This is not ideal as I would have liked completely separated views and using components forces me to declare them in the main view but it works well and is very easy to implement...
So: not as clean as I would have liked but much easier to implement and less convoluted.

Comment: Why don't you separate the views in different HTML files and just show and hide a <compose> elements?

Comment: That's more or less what I did actually. I didn't use a compose element because it allows me to define the view inline should it be necessary...

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Router View Ports
http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/router/latest/router-configuration/9

Comment: Thanks I can see how this helps with my second requirement (keep the state of the datagrid) but I don't really see how this can help me with my first requirement (replace or hide the content of the page). Can you elaborate on this?